# Android Studio Menubar creation

Tags: android, menu

so im getting into Android Development. Since i havent worked with it that much im missing the right keyword.

Basicly i want to create a menubar at the bottom of the screen with multiple options to select: "Home", "Contact", "Settings" etc. these menu items should open a new activity.

Is there a better way of creating this menubar than using ImageButtons?

Greetings,

Comment: Read this https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html and this https://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/index.html

Comment: and https://material.google.com/patterns/navigation.html#navigation-hierarchy and https://material.google.com/components/tabs.html

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of Android. I'm pretty new myself. Here is my advice to you, you can use xml and make the LinearLayouts buttons to launch your activity.

First make an xml file for your activity and regardless of it being a Linear or Relative layout make a new linearlayout nested at the bottom.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="64dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weight_sum="4">

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="+id/buttonName
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView Put your image stuff here/>
        <TextView Put your icon title here />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="your colour"/>
<!-- Repeat these Views and vertical Linear Layouts until you have the required amount -->
</LinearLayout>
```

You can then grab a reference to the linear Layouts using "buttonName" and have them as your bottom bar buttons.

It's probably not the most elegant solution but it worked for me.

Also if you need to hide the bar at anypoint just give the top linear layout an Id and set the visibility to Gone.